# MIN/MAX for strings?

Tags: sql, hive

I can do this:

```
create table newdata as
select id, min(timestamp) as time_start, max(timestamp) as time_stop
from mydata group by id;
```

if `timestamp` is a number (utc seconds).

However, suppose it is a string instead (`YYYYMMDDHH`).

I can use `unix_timestamp`, of course, but that seems an overkill because the next step will be

```
select time_start, time_stop, count(*)
from newdata group by time_start, time_stop;
```

and I will have to map to the string again.

So, what do people do for `min`/`max` on strings?

Comment: SQL supports `min()`/`max()` on strings, using alphabetical ordering.

Comment: Hive supports min/max on strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if Hive supports `min()`/`max()` on strings.  But yours are in a good format, so just convert them to numbers and work on that:

```
create table newdata as
    select id, min(cast(timestamp as bigint)) as time_start, max(cast(timestamp as bigint)) as time_stop
    from mydata
    group by id;
```

If you really want them as strings, you can convert them back afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

max/min method support string.